# Design Pattern to handle actions based on multiple inputs in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Let's say that there are two properties in a business model for eg., country and type, and we need to handle different logic for each country and for each type.

```
if(country=="us"){
    if(type=="type1){
        usType1Handler.Execute();
    }
    else if(type=="type2"){
        usType2Handler.Execute();
    }
    .
    .
    .
    else{
        usDefaultHandler.Execute();
    }
}
else if(country=="uk"){
    if(type=="type1){
        ukType1Handler.Execute();
    }
    else if(type=="type2"){
        ukType2Handler.Execute();
    }
    .
    .
    .
    else{
        ukDefaultHandler.Execute();
    }
}
else{
    throw exception("unknown country");
}
```

There will be lot of if's to mix and match the each implementation specific to each country type combination. Is there any design pattern we can use to handle this scenario?

Comment: Strategy Pattern... Large if-else blocks / switch statements are code-smells

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple. Just add all your handlers to a dictionary, where the key is the Country/Type combination, and the value is the handler function.

Create the dictionary and add all your handlers:

```
Dictionary<string, Handler> processor = new Dictionary<string, Handler>()
{
    { "us,type1", usType1Handler },
    { "us,type2", usType2Handler },
    { "us", usDefaultType2Handler },
    { "uk,type1", ukType1Handler },
}
//...etc
```

Then, simply search the dictionary and execute:

```
string key = String.Join(",", new[] { country, type })
bool success = processor.TryGetValue(key, out Handler handler);
if (success)
{
    handler.Execute();
}
else
{
    throw new Exception("unknown country");
}
```

Comment: thanks, this is the elegant solution for this problem and it's extensible too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of two patterns in order to improve this situation `Chain of Responsibility` && `Strategy Pattern`.

1. `Strategy Pattern` -- this pattern will help you to solve the country's conditional. You'll have to make an `AbstractCountryStrategy` + a concrete `Strategy` class for each country in our system.

The `Strategy` class will incapsulate a pretty simple line of code (the line that uses the other pattern `Chain of Responsibility`)

```
class USCountryStrategy {

    public void execute(type) {
        new USCountryTypeAHandler()
              .setNext(new USCountryTypeBHandler()
              .setNext(...))
           .executeBasedOn(type)
    }
}
```

2. `Chain of Responsibility` -- this pattern will help you to solve the type's conditional (but you'll still need to use a small if/else for this pattern just to check if your current handler has a next handler attached).

Overall Idea: For each type you'll have a small class that checks if it's able to solve your request ... similar to:

```
if(paramType.equals(this.type)
    this.execute();
    // if I can solve your request than I'll execute it myself
else if(this.next) 
    this.next.executeBasedOn(paramType);
    // if I can't solve your request than I'll pass it on to the next handler
else 
    throw RuntimeException(...)
    // nobody can solve your request (because I can't && this.next is null)
```

#### Is this useful or I'm just adding complexity to my code source?

Yes, it's useful when you have switch in your code, remember that soon you'll have to change this function/class. A switch is not extendable, is hard to maintain, gets very complex fast ("spaghetti code") and you might need to use it twice in your code base.

See https://github.com/kamranahmedse/design-patterns-for-humans for better & complete examples.

Comment: thanks for your inputs..There will be lot of concrete classes for each country. for eg. uscountrystrategy,  ukcountrystrategy  and so on. and from the client how to switch to correct strategy?  again it has to be either based on if statement or factory right?

Comment: Depends on the app's architecture. If you are working on a REST api you will know what `Strategy` to use from the endpoint's URL. If you work on an other type of app, you can use a `Dictionary<Location, CountryStrategy>` and get the right strategy by the key location (location can be a string or something else that defines the user's country). -- This works like a `Simple Factory` but don't use this too much because this is not a design pattern (hard to extend).

You can also use `Chain of Responsibility` again over `Strategy` -- but you will add to much complexity in your code source.

Comment: I want to point out that there is another way to get the right `Strategy`. If your strategy knows it's type (if you have a filed in your `Strategy` that describes the type using a `enum` or even a `string`), you can use reflection.
You find all the classes that implement `CountryStrategy` (the interface) -- and you put them into a list and you filter that list based on the country's type (and you get the first element).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend in this instance to use a nested switch:

```
switch (country)
{
    case "us":
        switch (type)
        {
            case "type1":
                usType1Handler.Execute();
                break;
            case "type2":
                usType2Handler.Execute();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        break;
    case "uk":
        switch (type)
        {
            case "type1":
                ukType1Handler.Execute();
                break;
            case "type2":
                ukType2Handler.Execute();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        break;
}
```

Comment: Complexity wise if-else ladders and Switches are equally problematic. They just differ in syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Your use case is well suited for a Strategy+Factory pattern implementation. You should have factories to move out the instantiation part for your handler. As you can see, we have not done away with if-else blocks but simply moved them to more manageable classes of their own. No doubt, it increases number of classes but this helps you make your code scaleable as well as less bug prone in the long run. You can add as many countries as you want without touching your existing code. This ensures you won't be introducing bugs in already existing functionality. Also, if you want you can have factory to return CountryFactory as well which would be even better. This way your "YourExecutingClass" would always remain untouched no matter how many countries and types you onboard in the future.

```cs
    public abstract class CountryFactory {
      protected abstract CountryTypeHandler getCountryTypeHandler(String type);
    }
    
    public class USHandlerFactory{
      @Override
      protected USHandlerFactory getCountryTypeHandler(String type){
        if(type=="type1"){
          return new USType1Handler();
        }
        else if(type=="type2"){
          return new USType2Handler();
        }
      }
    }

    public class UKHandlerFactory{
      @Override
      protected UKHandlerFactory getCountryTypeHandler(String type){
        if(type=="type1"){
          return new UKType1Handler();
        }
        else if(type=="type2"){
          return new UKType2Handler();
        }
      }
    }

    public void YourExecutingClass {
      USHandlerFactory handler; // Since this is your handler interface, it can hold any type of handler. You don't need to instantiate all your handlers. 
      
      String country = "us"; // Both country and type are input and can vary anyway you handle
      String type = "type1"; 
      CountryFactory factory;  
      if(country=="us"){
        factory = new USHandlerFactory();
      } else if(country=="uk") {
        factory = new UKHandlerFactory();
      }else{
        throw exception("unknown country");
      }

      handler = factory.getCountryTypeHandler(type);
      handler.Execute();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your input here...one question...There will one strategy for each country. and from the client how to switch to correct strategy?  again it has to be either based on if statement or factory right?

Comment: Since you are coding against abstract/interface, there are no ifs for handler. Check out my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Here the keyword is *execute()* and it has no_countries X no_types number of variations. To use OO approach you will have to distribute these many combinations in to different classes. At the cost of large number of concrete classes, you can buy extendable solution.

1. **Using Strategy**: somebody will have to hold/ create these strategies and provide when required. If strategy is not unique for country-type combination, then you save on variations. Strategy is typically useful when there is no state change.
2. **Chain of responsibility** - Here variations will be handled by handlers. Handler has to decide whether it can handle given case of not (may be based on country-type combo) but if a variation can handle multiple combinations then you will get small if-then in handler.

Both are extendable with some unavoidable cost.